# JavaFX8 FXML Controller initialize method not invoked

Tags: java, fxml

i'm trying to fill choice Box but something went wrong.
here is my code

Related part of Controller.java

```
public class BookingController implements Initializable {

   @FXML
   private ChoiceBox<String> orderType;       
   @Override
   public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) { 
        orderType=new ChoiceBox<>();
        orderType.getItems().add("LabShoot");
        orderType.getItems().add("SoftData");
        orderType.getItems().add("Booking");
    }    
}
```

FXML.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="447.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Orders.BookingController">
   <children>
      <ChoiceBox fx:id="orderType" layoutX="225.0" layoutY="59.0" onContextMenuRequested="#value_Changed" prefWidth="150.0" />
      <DatePicker layoutX="116.0" layoutY="118.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="173.0" />
      <ChoiceBox layoutX="387.0" layoutY="118.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="173.0" />
      <ChoiceBox layoutX="119.0" layoutY="188.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="173.0" />
      <ChoiceBox layoutX="387.0" layoutY="188.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="173.0" />
      <TextField layoutX="119.0" layoutY="257.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="173.0" />
      <TextField layoutX="388.0" layoutY="257.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="173.0" />
      <TextField layoutX="119.0" layoutY="325.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="173.0" />
      <Button layoutX="387.0" layoutY="325.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="173.0" text="Add" />
      <Label layoutX="30.0" layoutY="122.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="42.0" text="Date:" />
      <Label layoutX="214.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Customer Name" textFill="#2807ff">
         <font>
            <Font size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="336.0" layoutY="122.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="42.0" text="Time:" />
      <Label layoutX="22.0" layoutY="193.0" text="Booking Type:" />
      <Label layoutX="337.0" layoutY="192.0" text="Dealer:" />
      <Label layoutX="31.0" layoutY="329.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="42.0" text="Price:" />
      <Label layoutX="332.0" layoutY="261.0" text="Address:" />
      <Label layoutX="27.0" layoutY="261.0" text="Duration:" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

the program runs correctly but the items i put in choice box doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of

```
orderType=new ChoiceBox<>();
```

You should never intialize fields annoted with @FXML. If you do that your fields will no longer be referencing the ones loaded by the FXML Loader (and the ones who are displayed).

Comment: i did it but still same problem. i want to clear one thing more, i put
`System.out.println("invoked");` 
in the initialize method but it is also not printing. the main problem is that the initialize method not invoking.